# Contours around scipy labeled regions in a 2D grid

Tags: numpy, scipy, gis

I'm trying to find the bounding polygons of all of the wholes in a 2D grid with a large no-data value (1e6).  I've got the listing of holes working using scipy's label.  Without dipping into gdal's polygonalize, is there an easy way to generate the bounding polygons?  I see that there is matplotlib.pylab.contour, but this tries to draw a plot, which I really don't want.  Any recommendation on how to get bounding polygons for each label (preferably with a way to simplify the polygons a little if possible)?  I'm sure I can write something that will walk the bounds of each labelled hole, but is there something that already exists?

```
from osgeo import gdal
from scipy import ndimage

dem_file = gdal.Open('dem.tif')
dem = dem.file.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()

# Get a binary image of the no-data regions.  The no-data value is large
bin = dem > 9e5

# Find all the wholes.  Anything with a label > 0.
labels, num_labels = ndimage.measurements.label(bin)
num_labels
1063

# The hole's label and size. Skip 0 as that label has all the valid data.
holes = [(label, sum(labels==label)) for label in range(1, num_labels)]
holes[:3]
[(1, 7520492),
 (2, 1),
 (3, 1),]
```

e.g. rather than countouring, I'm looking for the bounds of all of these white regions as viewed in qgis, which was done with gdal_polygonalize.py.

[image: gdal_polygonalize.py contour plot in qgis]

Comment: I'm assuming by "bounding polygons", you mean the detailed outline rather than just the bounding box? (If you just want the bounding box, have a look at `scipy.ndimage.find_objects`.) "Vectorizing" a binary raster like this is something that's really missing from scipy, at the moment... In my experience, dropping back to gdal is usually the easiest and most robust way, but hopefully someone else knows a better way.

Comment: I knew I should have poked around more before saying that it was missing!  Have a look at scikits-image. `skimage.measure.find_contour` should do the basics, though it doesn't simplify the polygons at all, and doesn't distinguish inner rings (holes) from outer rings. http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_contours.html

Comment: Thanks Joe!  I will give scikits-image a go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Joe Kington for pointing me to Scikit Image.

```
from skimage import measure
contours = measure.find_contours(labels, 1)

contours[-1]
array([[ 2686.99905927,  1054.        ],
       [ 2686.        ,  1053.00094073],
       [ 2685.00094073,  1054.        ],
       [ 2686.        ,  1054.99905927],
       [ 2686.99905927,  1054.        ]])

imshow(labels)
for n, contour in enumerate(contours):
    plt.plot(contour[:,1], contour[:, 0], linewidth=2)
```

After zooming in the bottom left corner:

[image]