# Contours based on a "label mask"

Tags: matplotlib

I have images that have had features extracted with a contouring algorithm (I'm doing astrophysical source extraction).  This approach yields a "feature map" that has each pixel "labeled" with an integer (usually ~1000 unique features per map).

I would like to show each individual feature as its own contour.

One way I could accomplish this is:

```
for ii in range(labelmask.max()):
    contour(labelmask,levels=[ii-0.5])
```

However, this is very slow, particularly for large images.  Is there a better (faster) way?

P.S.
A little testing showed that [skimage's find-contours](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.find_contours) is no faster.

As per @tcaswell's comment, I need to explain why `contour(labels, levels=np.unique(levels)+0.5))` or something similar doesn't work:

```
1. Matplotlib spaces each subsequent contour "inward" by a linewidth to avoid overlapping contour lines.  This is not the behavior desired for a labelmask.
2. The lowest-level contours encompass the highest-level contours
3. As a result of the above, the highest-level contours will be surrounded by a miniature version of whatever colormap you're using and will have extra-thick contours compared to the lowest-level contours.
```

Comment: I would try either masking down the image you hand to contour to just the region of interest, extracting the path it gives back, and then shifting them to be in the right place.  Or use some sort of edge detection on your mask.

Comment: How would edge detection help?  I think the 'mask' image should already be as edgy as possible... are there routines that turn sharp edges into sets-of-points that can be used as contours?

Comment: This question is related and useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572933/contours-around-scipy-labeled-regions-in-a-2d-grid (describes `find_contours` and creating the `label` map I already have)

Comment: The second part is what I was thinking (turning the outline -> a path), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171039/sample-array-along-path .  That is essentially what `contour` is doing underneath, you might be able to same some time by skipping a bunch of the auxiliary work it does.

Comment: you should add the contents of your comment on my now deleted answer to your original question.

Comment: Thanks @tcaswell.  I think the sample-array-along-path solution may also work; may be worth posting as an answer since others may find opencv easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own... impatience (and good luck) got the better of me.

The key is to use matplotlib's low-level C routines:

```
I = imshow(data)
E = I.get_extent()
x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(E[0],E[1],labels.shape[1]), np.linspace(E[2],E[3],labels.shape[0]))

for ii in np.unique(labels):
    if ii == 0: continue
    tracer = matplotlib._cntr.Cntr(x,y,labels*(labels==ii))
    T = tracer.trace(0.5)
    contour_xcoords,contour_ycoords = T[0].T
    # to plot them:
    plot(contour_xcoords, contour_ycoords)
```

Note that `labels*(labels==ii)` will put each label's contour at a slightly different location; change it to just `labels==ii` if you want overlapping contours between adjacent labels.

Comment: Answering your own question is totally cool.  Remember to accept it as well.

Comment: Additional note: if you want the contours to be not-offset, use `tracer = matplotlib._cntr.Cntr(x,y,(labels==ii))` instead

Comment: you should edit your answer to include that note, comments are not stable.